# Working w/ Images SharePoint Online and Mobile

Tags: sharepoint-online, image, mobile, image-display

I was hoping to leverage SharePoint Asset Libraries to store Drone Photos.  The Department would like mobile support on iPhone as well.  Support seems to be limited.  While an Asset Library provides all of the functionality I need in terms of filtering and sorting (This will be a large collection of Photos), the library won't render on a mobile device.  It simply shows an image icon (Not a thumbnail of the photo) and the file name (which is useless)

I've added an image gallery to a page and this renders nicely on Mobile, but you have no sorting or filtering capability.

Must I start looking at third-party solutions?